# revokeObjectURL() doesn't work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, blob

I have a problem with Blob, already fixed the problem with IE but still can't open it on Safari. It shows  WebKitBlobResource error 1.

```js
  let blobData = new Blob([view], {
    type: "application/pdf"
  });

  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobData, documentName);
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") !== -1) {
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    window.open(url, "_blank");
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  } else {
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    window.open(url);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
})
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what version of Safari? and you should revoke the blob:// URI in the `onload` event of the Window object returned by  `open()` (well, you should not even use `open()` hack but rather `<a href="{ blobURI }" download="myfile.pdf">`)

Comment: It's Safari 13.1.1